# Agent Not Getting Run

Tags: java, containers, function-calls, agents-jade, agents

I think i am missing something in my project. I need agents to perform specific task that i assign. I am using JADE. Inside the `action()` i wrote a for loop to display numbers 1 to 10.
While running no error is showing and also the loop is not getting executed.
When i use *`java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot -gui agent:TestAgent`*, i am getting a `classNotFound` Exception and also shows agent can't be created. When i use *`java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot -gui -agent agent:TestAgent`*, I am getting info as agent ready, but the action method is not getting called.

Please guide me if i am doing in the wrong way.

*Exception is as below*

```
Mar 15, 2013 4:42:59 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents
SEVERE: Cannot create agent test: Class TestAgent for agent ( agent-identifier : name test@192.168.0.242:1099/JADE ) not found [nested java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestAgent]
Mar 15, 2013 4:42:59 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Main-Container@192.168.0.242 is ready.
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you could add the exception, stack trace, and minimal source code needed to reproduce the exception, it would be much easier to help.  Otherwise it's guesses and mind reading.

Comment: You have a error message: classNotFound Exception. Since you are not showing the complete error message, we cannot tell which class is missing. It could be "jade.Boot", so you have to check if jade.jar is available in the classpath. Or it could be your class TestAgent. Show us the complete output and we can provide a more precise explanation of what is happening.

Comment: I have included the exception trace that I got

Comment: possible duplicate of [JADE action() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425624/jade-action-not-working)