# JADE action() not working

Tags: java, containers, agent, agents-jade

I think I am missing something in my project. I need agents to perform specific task that I assign. I am using JADE. Inside the `action()` I wrote a for loop to display numbers 1 to 10. While running no error is showing and also the loop is not getting executed. When I run:

```
java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot -gui agent:TestAgent
```

I get a `classNotFound` Exception and also shows agent can't be created.

When I run:

```
java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot -gui -agent agent:TestAgent
```

I get info as agent ready, but the action method is not getting called.

What may be the reason? what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run jade in your IDE.
If you use netbeans, you can go to Project Properties -> Run:
Main Class: jade.Boot
Arguments: -gui agentName:packageName.AgentClassName (if you are using the Default Package use: agentName:AgentClassName)

Are you adding your Behaviour to your TestAgent in the `setup()` function?
You can do it using `addBehaviour(new myBehaviourClassName())`

One more thing you shouldn't use loop functions in agents or Behaviours (at least not big loops), use cyclic Behaviours (or SimpleBehaviours with the loop stop condition in the `done()` function)  instead and use the agent that owns the Behaviour to save the information you need to process only one or a few iterations of your "loop" in the `action()` function.

If you want to run jade from the command line use `java jade.Boot -gui agentName:TestAgent`
it will launch your agent in the main container.
If you are getting a **class not found error** check your current path in the cmd, it should be `projectPath\build\classes` (at least in a Netbeans Project, if you are using another IDE the path may be different).

Comment: When i use Netbeans, I am getting without any problem, but why am i not getting it in command line? What am i lacking or missing?

Comment: @Maximin Try to use `java jade.Boot -gui agent:TestAgent`

Comment: @Maximin I think that I found your problem, check the update in the answer.